# What is the difference between "screen -dm" and "screen -Dm"

Tags: bash, systemd, forking

I'm been looking for an explanation for the difference between `screen`'s `-dm` and `-Dm` options. I know that both options are used to make the screen run in the background / detach it after creation. I've read that the difference has something to do with forking, but I don't understand it.

I use `screen` to contain the console of my Minecraft server. When I called it directly in my `simple` systemd service, everything worked fine. However, when I moved the call to a script and called the script from the service, the service would exit when the script exits, stopping the Minecraft server with the `ExecStop` command. Some Googling revealed that I should use a `forking` service to prevent this, but that doesn't solve the issue, and I cannot use a `oneshot` service that doesn't exit, as I need the system to be able to detect if the Minecraft server is still running.

I currently call `screen` the following way:

```
screen -DmS minecraft java -jar server.jar nogui &
```

I use the `&` to fork the process and keep the screen from freezing the shell.

Since the service fails due to not forking properly, and the difference between the `-Dm` and `-dm` options has something to do with forking, I suspect that's where the problem is.

Could someone explain to me what the practical difference between these options is, and how I can use screen properly in a forking service?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please stick to one site: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59167893/7552, https://askubuntu.com/q/1193654/10127 -- this is the appropriate site for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll remove the others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just quoting the manual here:

```
-d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but
        doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

-D -m   This  also  starts  screen  in "detached" mode, but doesn't fork a new process.
        The command exits if the session terminates.
```